# How can we call println without it being called on an object in Scala and how does it have side effects?

Tags: scala

How is it possible to call print() or println() without having the object on the left side? Also how are these two methods having a side effect? How would one determine if there is a side effect or not? All they do is give output to the console and not change anything from my understanding.

Comment: What do you mean in this case with side effects?

Comment: And you're right in your understanding. Are you experiencing anything you could attribute to side effects of their invocation?

Comment: Printing to the console is considered a side effect

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez from my understanding a side effect is when you are making a change and not simply returning a value. While I cannot understand how is input or output such as println considered a side effect in functional programming if all they do is output a value to the screen, which is returning a value, or taking in a value.

Comment: @VividMan You can define a side effect as anything that breaks referential transparency. Thus if `val a = println("Hello, World")` and then `val b = (a, a)` then b must be the same as `(println("Hello, World"), println("Hello, World"))` but it is not. As a value it is the same, it is a tuple of two units, but the first program printed hello world once and the second one twice, thus there was a side effect. - _"How would one determine if there is a side effect"_ impossible to do, it is  basically a variation of the halting problem.

Answer (score 1):

`println()` is defined in `Predef.scala`

> The Predef object provides definitions that are accessible in all
>   Scala compilation units without explicit qualification.

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html

To check for side effect, you'll have to see what is actually being passed to `println()`. Demo in the below snippet:

```
object Test extends App {
  var x = 10
  def hello(): String = "hello"

  def helloWithSideEffect(): String = {
    x = 11
    "hello again"
  }

  println(x)
  println(hello())
  println(x)
  println(helloWithSideEffect())
  println(x)
}
```

Result

```
10
hello
10
hello again
11
```